# DevArt postgres in AzureDevops

Tags: azure-devops, devart

I'm working on a local build application that requires DevArt dotnet Connect for Postgres. I'm trying to set up the build pipeline in Azure DevOps, but I can't find the extension for Postgres in the extensions marketplace. Any guidance on how to obtain DevArt dotnet Connect for Postgres in Azure DevOps would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean how to restore the package "**`Devart.Data.PostgreSql`**" to your application when building the application in the pipeline of Azure DevOps?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to restore "**`Devart.Data.PostgreSql`**" package when building your application in the pipeline of Azure DevOps, you can follow the steps below to configure:

1. Open your application in Visual Studio.
2. Right click on the project which needs "**`Devart.Data.PostgreSql`**" package, and select "**Manage NuGet Packages...**" option.
3. Under the **Browse** tab, search for and install "**`Devart.Data.PostgreSql`**" package.

   [image]
4. Save and push the changes to the remote repo.
5. In the pipeline, if you use the [VSBuild](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/vsbuild-v1?view=azure-pipelines) or [MSBuild](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/msbuild-v1?view=azure-pipelines) task to build the application, before the build task, you need to add a [NuGet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/nuget-command-v2?view=azure-pipelines) task like as below to run '**`nuget restore`**' to restore the required packages from **`NuGet.org`**.

   [image]

---

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am able to run in Visual Studio but when do the same in azure DevOps getting this error. .nuget\NuGet.targets(100,9): Error : Unable to find version '7.22.2014' of package 'Devart.Data.PostgreSql

Comment: @valpravin, Have you followed the steps mentioned above to configure you project and pipeline?

Comment: @valpravin, I noticed you have opened [a new ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77676029/unable-to-build-the-project-in-azuredevops) for the "**`Unable to find version of package`**" error. I have shared some suggestions in my answer on that new ticket. Check and try it.