# Unable to build the project in AzureDevops

Tags: azure-devops, nuget, nuget-package-restore

Unable to build the my application in AzureDevops please help

Code Snip

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-2019'

variables:
  solution: 'sample.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    restoreSolution: 'sample.sln'
    feedsToUse: 'select'
    
- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)\WebApp.zip" /p:DeployIisAppPath="sample"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
```

Reference Error from Azure Devops:

```
2023-12-17T07:36:28.2707587Z Restoring NuGet packages...
2023-12-17T07:36:28.2708450Z To prevent NuGet from downloading packages during build, open the Visual Studio Options dialog, click on the Package Manager node and uncheck 'Allow NuGet to download missing packages'.
Error : Unable to find version '4.2.1' of package 'AutoMapper'.
Error : Unable to find version '1.0.0' of package 'CommonServiceLocation'.
Error : Unable to find version '5.0.2806' of package 'Devart.Data'.
Error : Unable to find version '7.22.2014' of package 'Devart.Data.PostgreSql'.
Error : Unable to find version '6.1.3' of package 'EntityFramework'.
Error : Unable to find version '2.0.5' of package 'log4net'.
Error : Unable to find version '3.9.1' of package 'LumenWorksCsvReader'.
```

please help what is wrong.

followed these steps too#
[DevArt postgres in AzureDevops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77651530/devart-postgres-in-azuredevops)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to configure your **`NuGet.config`** like as below to fix the issue:

1. Add below contents to your **`NuGet.config`**. For more details, see "[**`nuget.config` reference**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-config-file)".

   ```xml
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <configuration>
     <packageRestore>
       <!-- Enable NuGet can perform automatic restore. -->
       <add key="enabled" value="True" />
       <!-- Enable NuGet can check for missing packages during a build. -->
       <add key="automatic" value="True" />
     </packageRestore>

     <packageSources>
       <!-- Add nuget.org as a package source. -->
       <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
       <!-- Add the custom artifact feeds as the package sources. -->
       <add key="CustomFeed" value="{URL of the CustomFeed}" />
     </packageSources>

     <disabledPackageSources />

     <activePackageSource>
       <!-- Active all non-disabled package sources. -->
       <add key="All" value="(Aggregate source)" />
     </activePackageSource>

     . . .
   </configuration>
   ```
2. In the pipeline, you just need one **`NuGetCommand@2`** task to restore the packages by using the **`NuGet.config`**.
3. If your '**`CustomFeed`**' is a private feed, you may need to add the [**`NuGetAuthenticate@1`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/nuget-authenticate-v1?view=azure-pipelines) task to get the credentials to access the private feed before the **`NuGetCommand@2`** task.

---